# display ap.net web api returned result to mvc view

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I creating a web application using mvc project and web api separate projects I am using identity for registering users.
My question is when the web api returns the result how can I display it in MVC view

this is my web api controller -

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);



        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

    }
```

AND THIS is how i am calling this web api -

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterView model)
    {
        //
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //The URL of the WEB API Service
        string url = "http://localhost:51493/Api/Account/Register";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        //

        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        else{//pass the validation errors in view and display it in view}
    }
}
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: You pass the result of your web api call as the model, or part of the model, to the view that you want to display it in. Its no different than using any other external piece of data that you want to display in your View. What is different is that you should be able to accomplish this as well using client code to hit the Web API instead of going back to the server.

Comment: can u elaborate with the help of code i am a beginner an .net framework
thanks in advanve :)

Comment: Then I recommend you run through some tutorials or books on how MVC works and how to display data in Views.

Answer (score 0):

remove `else`, it's not necessary.

Add

```
return View(model);
```

Also, enable unobtrusive validation in your view

Comment: @alez ovechkin how can i pass the returned response message of web api along with the model in return View(model); statement

Comment: You can use your response in ModelState.AddError()

Comment: Thanks @Alex now i am validation errors in my view but it is appearing like this
       {"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"":["Name haseeb@yahoo.com is already taken.","Email 'haseeb@yahoo.com' is already taken."]}}

how can i only display the message i-e name haseeb@yahoo.com is already taken nothiing else and errors should be displayed right above the  thst textbox to which validation is failed

Comment: I guess you should pass only ModelState, not "The request is invalid". You can deserialize response, get only ModelState and pass it to your view